# How to Re-direct from gateway to authorization server. In BFF (Backend for frontend) Pattern

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have gateway acts as a OAuth2 client(port: 8080). And I have created a OAuth2 Server(port:9000).

When I start both projects. try to fetch : localhost:8080/login it shows me message auth2 login localhost:9000 . when i click on this it gives me 400 error.

POM (client (BFF))

```
server:
  port: 8080

#issuer-uri: This is the URL where the OAuth 2.0 authorization server can be found.

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          myprovider:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
        registration:
          myclient:
            provider: myprovider
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token
            scope: openid, profile, user.read, user.write
            client-id: "client"
            client-secret: "{noop}secret"
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:9000/login
#            redirect-uri: "http://test"
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: api_product
          uri: http://localhost:8081
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/product/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/api/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
            - TokenRelay=
```

POM (Auth server)

```
server:
  port: 9000

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: INFO

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          client:
            registration:
              client-id: "client"
              client-secret: "{noop}secret"
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "authorization_code"
                - "refresh_token"
              redirect-uris:
                - "http://test"
              scopes:
                - "openid"
                - "profile"
                - "user.read"
                - "user.write"
            require-authorization-consent: false
            require-proof-key: true
```

when type localhost:8080. it should redirect to auth server for authentication.
it should redirect to localhost:9000/login to login form for authentication. but it gives me 400 error. I am using code grant flow as client credentials are deprecated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.